# Calculate the limit of nested log fractions

Tags: python, limit, fractions

Here's a pic of the fractions of logs of n, where n grows as n*2 + 1 for each increase in 'nested' fraction level:
[image]

My code doesn't let me go beyond d = 512+1 and I get a math domain error. Which might suggest I'm dividing the wrong logs with each other?

```
import math
dlist = []
d = 1
while d < 2**9:
    for i in range(d+1):
        dlist.append(i+2)
    n = 2
    while len(dlist) < d*2 + 1:
        dlist.append(math.log(dlist[n-1]) / math.log(dlist[n-2]))
        n = n + 2
    print(n,dlist[len(dlist)-1])
    dlist = []
    d = d*2 + 1
```

Comment: interesting problem... have you tried to apply the chain of base formula of the _log_? By using mathematics (and get an explicit formula) you can reduce the complexity of the problem

Comment: it could be that the base of the _log_ converges to smt less than 1 (maybe due to the fact that  _float_ != real numbers ). My last value before the _math domain error_ is 0.2517036348629797

Comment: @cards, I just increased the precision of the values with Decimal(). 


`import math
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 280
dlist = []
d = 1
while d < 2**30:
 for i in range(d+1):
  dlist.append(Decimal(i+2))
 n = 2
 while len(dlist) < d*2 + 1:
  dlist.append(Decimal( Decimal(dlist[n-1]).ln() / Decimal(dlist[n-2]).ln()))
  n = n + 2
 print(n,Decimal(dlist[len(dlist)-1]))
 dlist = []
 d = d*2 + 1`

Comment: I had also that idea but I wanted to implement a version with the [change of base formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Change_of_Base_of_Logarithm) for the log but `Decimal` support only base _10_ or _e_ :(

Comment: By the way I don't know how the extra digits are added... it seems a bit of spam, check this example with just 1/3: `getcontext().prec = 50
d = Decimal(1/3)
exact = Decimal(f'0.{"3"*54}') print(d) print(exact)`